# How to open a block of comments on PgAdmin query editor?

Tags: postgresql, comments, pgadmin

There are 2 ways to mark comment in pgAdmin - PostgreSQL:
the

1. `-- bla bla`

and the:

2. `/* bla bla 
   bla bla*/`

for the first one i use ctrl+k as short hot key.
is there a hot key for the 2nd one? i know ctrl+k can be applied on muliple lines if i mark them but it will add -- for all lines which isn't what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 12):

I use pgadmin 4 (4.28) and `ctrl+/` comments the lines and `ctrl+shift+/` uncomments the lines

Answer (score 11):

Apple Mac ()

- Comment:   <kbd>⌘ Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>
- Uncomment: <kbd>⌘ Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd>

Comment: This worked for me. Link to the official documentation : https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/7.6/keyboard_shortcuts.html#sql-editors

Answer (score 9):

Ctrl k will comment out a block of code, while Ctrl-Shift k will uncomment out the block.

Ctrl k --> Comment,
Ctrl K --> Uncomment (capitalize k)

Comment: version 1.3, this does not work for me and I cannot ctrl + s to save either.

Comment: I'm using pgadmin4 (4.19) and `ctrl + /` works to comment and `ctrl + shift + /` uncomments the lines.

Answer (score 0):

**Windows** 
**pgAdmin 4:** 
 '/' on the keyboard's letter side worked for me not on the number side!

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu GNU/LInux (PgAdmin4), select a block of code with the mouse cursor.

#### Comment

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>}</kbd>

#### UNcomment

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>}</kbd>